# jQuery onsubmit function using incorrect target element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Really stuck on this one, I've inherited a website that was built using a page builder *vomits*

I've created a script that guards the downloads on this page (resources) the user must fill out a form and input their details, the form submission works correctly and when it completes I open the resource using `window.open(href, '_blank')` this works correctly on the first submit but if you try and download a second resource it always returns the first clicked href and opens that.

Here is my code: Im getting all the anchors on the page, looping over them and adding an onClick event listener, when a user clicks the link it opens the modal, then jquery to submit the form. As you can see in the comments the href is logged correctly when outside of the submit function, however when inside the submit function it always reverts back to the first href clicked.

> e.g user clicks resource1, submits the form and downloads, user then clicks resource2, submits the form but is directed to resource1 :'(

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  const anchors = Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.page-id-17757 .elementor-element-7121f28 .elementor-widget-icon-list a')
  );

  const modal = document.querySelector('#resources-modal');

  function getFormData($form) {
    var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
    var indexed_array = {
      data: {},
    };

    $.map(unindexed_array, function (n, i) {
      indexed_array.data[n['name']] = n['value'];
    });
    return indexed_array;
  }

  function updateFormResponse(status, anchor) {
    if (status == 200) {
      $('.form-response').html('Success.');
      modal.close();
      $('.form-response').html('');
      $('#resources-submit').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('.form-response').html('There has been an error, please refresh the page and try again');
      $$('#resources-submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
  }

  anchors.forEach((anchor) => {
    anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal.showModal();
      let href = e.target.parentElement.href;
      $('.resources-download').submit(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        let form = $(this);
        $('#resources-submit').prop('disabled', true);
        let formData = getFormData(form);
        $.ajax({
          url: '/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor/raisley/resources-download.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          complete: function (data) {
            updateFormResponse(data.status, href);
            if (data.status == 200) downloadResource();
          },
        });
      });
      console.log(href); // this logs the correct href
      function downloadResource() {
        console.log(href); // logs incorrect href, always returns the first clicked href
        window.open(href, '_blank');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I'm really struggling with this one, need some pro help please!

Thanks,

Comment: It's almost always wrong adding an event handler inside another event handler. Each time you click on an anchor, it adds another submit handler to `.resources-download`, without removing the previous ones. So when you submit that form, it runs all the previous handlers as well as the latest one.

Comment: The simple fix is to do `$(".resources-download").off("submit").submit(function ...)` to remove the old handlers first.